# SQL Server CTE giving execution issue

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

Here is my CTE - it is causing an error. Help me to figure out the error

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[myEmpTab](
[EMPNO] [int] NULL,
[ENAME] [varchar](10)  NULL,
[JOB] [varchar](20)  NULL,
[MGR] [int] NULL,
[HIREDATE] [datetime] NULL,
[SAL] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

;
WITH MyCTE AS 
( 
  SELECT EMPNO, EName, Null as MGR, NULL as ManagerName
  FROM myEmpTab
  WHERE MGR IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  EMPNO, EName, MGR, MyCTE.EName
  FROM myEmpTab
  INNER JOIN MyCTE ON myEmpTab.MGR = MyCTE.EMPNO
  WHERE myEmpTab.MGR IS NOT NULL 
)
SELECT * FROM MyCTE
```

when i am executing the sql then i am getting error like

```
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
Ambiguous column name 'EMPNO'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
Ambiguous column name 'EName'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
Ambiguous column name 'MGR'.
```

i am not being able to catch the error . so please anyone have a lot and help me to fix it. thanx.

Comment: what error ? try with ';WITH' at the beginning

Comment: Use `Select myEmpTab.EMPNO, myEmpTab.EName` esp. in the second query in the CTE. Those columns belong to more than one table or result and it didn't know which to pick

Comment: can u give example...things is not clear.

Comment: in the SELECT statements in the CTE, precede the column names with their table name, the table they belong to e.g. `Select myEmpTab.EMPNO, myEmpTab.EName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can reference a CTE inside itself. Try this

```
WITH MyCTE AS 
( 
SELECT EMPNO, EName, MGR, Sal
FROM myEmpTab
WHERE MGR IS NULL
)

SELECT EMPNO, EName, MGR, Sal FROM MyCTE

UNION ALL

SELECT  e.EMPNO, e.EName, e.MGR, MyCTE.EName
FROM myEmpTab e
INNER JOIN MyCTE ON e.MGR = MyCTE.EMPNO
WHERE e.MGR IS NOT NULL
```

OR

```
WITH MyCTE AS 
( 
    SELECT EMPNO, EName, MGR, Sal
    FROM myEmpTab
    WHERE MGR IS NULL
),
MyCTE2 as
(
    SELECT EMPNO, EName, MGR, Sal FROM MyCTE

    UNION ALL

    SELECT  e.EMPNO, e.EName, e.MGR, MyCTE.EName
    FROM myEmpTab e
    INNER JOIN MyCTE ON e.MGR = MyCTE.EMPNO
    WHERE e.MGR IS NOT NULL 
)
SELECT * FROM MyCTE2
```

Comment: Yes you can reference a CTE inside itself. As in a recursive CTE.  The OP's code is fine to recurse an employment hierarchy, just missing a final `SELECT FROM MyCTE`

Comment: Thanks for that. May be I didn't try it well in the SSMS. I'll try that again.

Comment: i edited my code. now i give my full sql. please have look and tell me what is wrong in my sql.

Answer (score 1):

Following your edit you presumably need something like

```
;WITH MyCTE AS 
( 
  SELECT EMPNO, EName, NULL as MGR, CAST(Null AS  VARCHAR(10)) as ManagerName
  FROM myEmpTab
  WHERE MGR IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  myEmpTab.EMPNO, myEmpTab.EName, MyCTE.MGR, MyCTE.EName
  FROM myEmpTab
  INNER JOIN MyCTE ON myEmpTab.MGR = MyCTE.EMPNO
  WHERE myEmpTab.MGR IS NOT NULL 
)
SELECT * FROM MyCTE
```

Comment: I guessed that much but I thought the OP intentionally left it out as if it was not relevant